# 2 html pages linked via javascript function

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="instructionstext"></p>Have fun!</p>
        <button onclick="onButtonClick()">I dare you to click me!</button>
```

JavaScript - how can I add the link for forwarding to the second html page?

```
function onButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('instructionstext').innerHTML = "&#128561";
    console.log("Secret message");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function onButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('instructionstext').innerHTML = "&#128561";
    console.log("Secret message");
    window.location.href = "http://www.second-link.com";
}
```